# x86 Assembly: Bootloader doesn't load program

Tags: x86, bootloader

In the last few days I've been trying to play with making an operating system and I started by making a bootloader. I am specifically trying to load a small sample program to test it. This is the bootloader code:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16
start: jmp boot

boot:
    cli                               ; Disable interrupts
    cld                               ; Clear direction flags


    mov al, 2                         ; Read 2 sectors
    mov ch, 0                         ; Track 0
    mov cl, 2                         ; Read 2nd sector (1st sector is bootloader)
    mov dh, 0                         ; Head number
    mov dl, 0                         ; Drive number (0 = floppy drive)

    ; Specify memory address to read floppy to
    mov bx, 0x5000
    mov es, bx
    xor bx, bx

    mov ah, 0x2                       ; INT 0x13 with AH=0x2 means read sector
    int 0x13                          ; Call BIOS to read sector
    jmp 0x5000:0x0000                 ; Jump to sector

  ; Must be 512 bytes
  times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
  dw 0xAA55                           ; Boot Signature
```

And this is the sample program code:

```
msg db "Welcome to kOS!", 0ah, 0dh, 0h

start: jmp moveCursor

moveCursor:
    mov ah, 0x2                       ; INT 0x10 with AH=0x2 means set cursor position
    mov bh, 0                         ; Page number
    mov dh, 12                        ; Row
    mov dl, 0                         ; Column
    int 0x10                          ; Call BIOS to set position
    jmp putChar

putChar:
    mov ah, 0xA                       ; INT 0x10/AH=0xA means write character
    mov al, 0x48                      ; Character H
    mov bh, 0                         ; Page number
    mov cx, 1                         ; Times to write character
    int 0x10                          ; Call BIOS to write character
    jmp print

print:
    mov si, msg          ; Move starting address of message into SI
    jmp printstring

printstring:
    xor ax, ax           ; Set AX to 0
    mov ds, ax           ; Set Data Segment to 0
    lodsb                ; Load byte at Data Segment into AL, increment SI
    or al, al            ; Check if AL is 0
    jz exitloop          ; If zero exit the loop
    mov ah, 0xE          ; INT 0x10/AH=0xE means teletype output
    int 0x10             ; Call BIOS to write character
    jmp printstring      ; Repeat for next character

exitloop:
    hlt                  ; Halt the system
```

However, debugging this with QEMU/GDB, I see that the jump from the bootloader code never happens (I set a breakpoint at address 0x5000 but it never reaches it), and the program never runs. I've found many questions with the same problem here, but their solutions didn't help me. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So what *does* happen?  Can you single-step the first part of the boot sector and see how far you get?  The Bochs emulator has a more convenient debugger than QEMU for such things.  It also may be that your breakpoint isn't set where you think it is.

Comment: Note that you've got your string as the first thing in your "application".  If you assemble this in the obvious way, it'll be the first thing in the sector, so that's where you will jump and you'll try to execute the string, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: By the way, why all the pointless instances where you jump to a label which is the next instruction anyway?  Just paranoia about possible future rearrangement of the code, or are you perhaps confused as to how control flow in assembly language works? Some beginners tend to treat labels like subroutines, which they're not.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks a lot for telling me about the string, I didn't know about that. Also, checking the execution line by line, I see that after the jump, my code is not there, it goes back to what I believe is QEMU's BIOS code at address 0x2. And yes, I indeed don't have too much experience with Assembly, I wasn't sure if control flow works like that. Thanks for the tips!